# Roots of second order trigonometric polynomial

Tags: analysis, trigonometry

I am trying to find the roots of a trigonometric polynomial of the following type:

$f(x)=A\cos x + B\sin x + C \cos(2x) + D \sin(2x)$

with $A, B, C, D \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x\in[-\pi,\pi]$

I couldn't think of any useful substitution. Any ideas how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Use Euler's formulas $\sin{x}=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}, \cos{x}=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$.., and then $e^{ix}=y$. B this you arive at an equation of grade IV.

Comment: Use the tangent half-angle substitution and get a quartic equation.

Comment: @Vasile of course, thanks! That works, but even mathematica seems to be struggling with the resubstitution of the solution into real trigonometric functions.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici that seems to be the better approach by avoiding the complex resubstitution. Thanks!

Comment: I think it is simpler because you can solve quartic equations with (nasty) radicals.